# How to style a button tabbed state when its default behviour is prevented in Javascript

Tags: jquery, html, css

In the example there is a button labeled "tab" and the css is not the same as other buttons (it seems disabled). I want the borders of that button to be black while key down or tabbed like other buttons. I know it is because of  e.preventDefault(); but if i am removing it my functionality stops.

Is there a way around this?

See fiddle **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t4ce2jtu/16/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <input type="button" class="tab"  value="Tab"/>
 <input type="text"   class="ans1"  style="border-color:black">
 <div class="def1"><i>Hundreds</i></div>
 <input type="text"  class="ans2" style="border-color:black">
 <div class="def2"><i>Tens</i></div>
 <input type="text"  class="ans3" style="border-color:#000;">
 <div class="def3"><i>Ones </i><b style="margin-left:30px;"></b> </div>
 <input type="text"  class="ans4" style="border-color:#000;">
 <input type="button"  class="num" id="one" value="1" />
 <input type="button" class="num" id="two" value="2" />
 <input type="button"  class="num" id="three" value="3" />
 <input type="button" class="num" id="four" value="4" />
 <input type="button" class="num" id="five" value="5" />
 <input type="button" class="num" id="six" value="6" />
 <input type="button" class="num" id="seven" value="7" />
 <input type="button" class="num" id="eight" value="8" />
 <input type="button" class="num" id="nine" value="9" />
 <input type="button" class="num" id="zero" value="0" />
 <input type="button" class="clear" value="Clear"/>
 <input type="button" class="delete"  value="Back"/>
 <input type="button" class="tab"  value="Tab"/>
</div>
```

---

Comment: fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/t4ce2jtu/16/

Answer (score 1):

In your css, style it as you want. The `:active` is a pseudo selector to select on whether the button is 'active'. I.E. When it is in a  `mousedown` state.

```
.tab:active{
   border:1px solid black;
}
```

Although you can fiddle with this to style it as you wish.

---

To style 'all buttons' on mouse down, you could use something like:

```
input[type="button"]:active{    /*all input buttons on mousedown */
    outline:0;                  /*remove default outline from all*/
    border:1px solid pink;      /*add styling as you wish*/
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/t4ce2jtu/20/)**

---

After reading up on firefox, I found that it doesn't like the e.preventDefault() being used on a 'mousedown' event handler, whilst maintaining an 'active' css. Changing this to a 'click' event allows Firefox to accept the button as a button input, and hence can be used as such:

```
$('.tab').on('click', function (e) {     /*THIS BIT CHANGED*/
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
    ...
});
```

Comment: tab button is not working same as other buttons on clicking the border color is changing to pink of all buttons except  tab button

Comment: @ jbutler483 i am trying it from morning but of no use can u help me.

Comment: @NITISHDHAWAN: I can't reproduce your issue in the fiddle. Which browser are you using?

Comment: but if i change the event handler to click there is another issue my .tab button functionality is changing. @jbutler483

Comment: Seems like an issue with the newer FF versions. Tested on FF19 and works fine.