# e.preventDefault() causing error

Tags: jquery, html

In the example there is a button labeled "tab" when i am clicking it ,its border color doesn't change as if it is disabled but it is not . I know it is because of e.preventDefault(); but if i am removing it my  my functionality stops.  Is there a way around this? and this is happening only in Firefox.

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <input type="button" class="tab"  value="Tab"/>
 <input type="text"   class="ans1"  style="border-color:black">
 <div class="def1"><i>Hundreds</i></div>
 <input type="text"  class="ans2" style="border-color:black">
 <div class="def2"><i>Tens</i></div>
 <input type="text"  class="ans3" style="border-color:#000;">
 <div class="def3"><i>Ones </i><b style="margin-left:30px;"></b> </div>
 <input type="text"  class="ans4" style="border-color:#000;">
 <input type="button"  class="num" id="one" value="1" />
 <input type="button" class="num" id="two" value="2" />
 <input type="button"  class="num" id="three" value="3" />
 <input type="button" class="num" id="four" value="4" />
 <input type="button" class="num" id="five" value="5" />
 <input type="button" class="num" id="six" value="6" />
 <input type="button" class="num" id="seven" value="7" />
 <input type="button" class="num" id="eight" value="8" />
 <input type="button" class="num" id="nine" value="9" />
 <input type="button" class="num" id="zero" value="0" />
 <input type="button" class="clear" value="Clear"/>
 <input type="button" class="delete"  value="Back"/>
 <input type="button" class="tab"  value="Tab"/>
</div>
```

Comment: fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/t4ce2jtu/19/

Comment: guys this is fiddle of the problrm help me

Comment: y cant u add " $(this).css("border","1px solid red");" before e.preventDefault();

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style a button tabbed state when its default behviour is prevented in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28428303/how-to-style-a-button-tabbed-state-when-its-default-behviour-is-prevented-in-jav)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is issue of firefox.

You can use JQuery like following to show the effect:

```
$('.tab').on('mousedown', function (e) {
    $(this).css("border","1px solid black");
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('.tab').on('mouseup', function (e) {
    $(this).css("border","none");
});
```

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ketan156/t4ce2jtu/36/) here.

Comment: :D yes may be. but, hope for solving the issue required to do it.

Comment: Hey. tushar have you check fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is due to Mozilla having a different opinion on exactly how much of the default behaviour should be prevented by preventDefault, compared to the other browser vendors.

That said, I'd probably go for adding a class to the button on mousedown, and removing it again on mouseup.

Answer (score 0):

The issue being Firefox not showing the Button click animation as you are handling the mousedown event. You can use the click event and hold the current tab by adding a class to the input field and moving it to the next element on click of the event.

```
$('.tab').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var inFocus = $('.current').removeClass('current');
if (inFocus.length) {
    var focusIndex = focusAbles.index(inFocus);
    if (focusIndex + 1 < focusAbles.length) {
        focusAbles.eq(focusIndex + 1).focus().addClass('current');

    } else {
        focusAbles.eq(0).focus().addClass('current');
    };
} else {
    focusAbles.eq(0).focus().addClass('current');
};
```

});

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4ce2jtu/38/).

Answer (score 0):

No need to css styles for input element

**JQUERY:**

```
$( "input.inputAns" ).css({"border":"1px solid #b8b8b8"});
var focusAbles = $('.wrapper').find('input[type=text]');
$('.tab').on('mousedown', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $( "input.inputAns" ).focus(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).css({"border":"1px solid #323232"});
        });
    $( "input.inputAns" ).focusout(function(e) {

        $(this).css({"border":"1px solid #b8b8b8"});
       e.preventDefault();
    });
    var inFocus = $(':focus');
    if (inFocus.length) {
        var focusIndex = focusAbles.index(inFocus);
        if (focusIndex + 1 < focusAbles.length) {
            focusAbles.eq(focusIndex + 1).focus();

        } else {
            focusAbles.eq(0).focus();
        };
    } else {
        focusAbles.eq(0).focus();
    };
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<input type="button" class="tab"  value="Tab"/>

<input type="text"   class="ans1 inputAns"  style="border-color:black">
<div class="def1"><i>Hundreds</i></div>
<input type="text"  class="ans2 inputAns" style="border-color:black">
<div class="def2"><i>Tens</i></div>
<input type="text"  class="ans3 inputAns" style="border-color:#000;">
<div class="def3"><i>Ones </i><b style="margin-left:30px;"></b> </div>
<input type="text"  class="ans4 inputAns" style="border-color:#000;">

    <input type="button"  class="num" id="one" value="1" />
                        <input type="button" class="num" id="two" value="2" />
                        <input type="button"  class="num" id="three" value="3" />
                        <input type="button" class="num" id="four" value="4" />
                         <input type="button" class="num" id="five" value="5" />
                          <input type="button" class="num" id="six" value="6" />
                          <input type="button" class="num" id="seven" value="7" />
                          <input type="button" class="num" id="eight" value="8" />
                          <input type="button" class="num" id="nine" value="9" />
                          <input type="button" class="num" id="zero" value="0" />
                          <input type="button" class="clear" value="Clear"/>
                          <input type="button" class="delete"  value="Back"/>

                          <input type="button" class="tab"  value="Tab"/>
    </div>
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/t4ce2jtu/39/